# Handle JS classes with import statements in html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 files.

1. Connections.js
2. Main.html.
3. ScriptFile.js

I am copying only small part of the code here.

Connection.js has a class

```
import {net} from 'net';
export class connect {
Testfunction() {return "something"}
}
```

main.html has a function

```
<html> 
<head>
        <script src= 'Connections.js'></script>
        <script src= 'ScriptFile.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my text color.</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

ScriptFile.js

```
import { connect } from "./Connections.js";
const ObjConnect = new connect()
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ObjConnect.Testfunction();

  }
```

How do I make "text" in my html file to change to "something" when I click on it?

Comment: The *ScriptFile.js* cannot use `import` if it's a script and not `type="module"`. Do you want to use scripts, or do you want to use modules? Don't mix them.

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo at file name.
It's Connection, not Connections in `main.js`

**Case1. using module**

- main.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="Connection.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="ScriptFile.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo">Click me to change my text color.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

- ScriptFile.js

```
import { connect } from './Connection.js';

const ObjConnect = new connect();
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ObjConnect.Testfunction();
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

**Case2. using script**

- main.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Connection.js"></script>
    <script src="ScriptFile.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Connection.js

```
class connect {
  Testfunction() {
    return 'something';
  }
}
```

- ScripFile.js

```
const ObjConnect = new connect();
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ObjConnect.Testfunction();
}
```

Comment: hi, I get myFunction not found error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, about how to use modules (export/import) in a HTML file and I found it works like so:

My javascript module:

```
class jsGrid {
   #baseElem = ''
   #dataURL = ''
   
   constructor(elemId, url) {
      this.#baseElem = document.getElementById(elemId)
      this.#dataURL = url
      console.log(this.#dataURL)
   }

}

export { jsGrid }
```

Notice the curly brackets for the exported items.

Then, in my HTML file I added a `script` tag, before closing the `body` tag:

```
      <script type="module">
         import { jsGrid } from './jsGrid.js'
         let dataURL = 'https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/beers?size=25'
        
         let grid = new jsGrid('.jsGrid', dataURL)
      </script>
   </body>
```

Notice here the use of the `type` attribute to specify a `module`.

May this help someone else.